# PHP Barcode Image Generator

Tags: php, barcode

I require a class which will generate barcode image files, preferably compatible with the most common standards.

I'm looking for recommendations / suggestions based on personal experiences with such things.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple PHP script for generating barocdes:

```
<?php
//For displaying barcodes

//Arguments are:
//  code    Number you want outputted as a barcode

//You can use this script in two ways:
//  From a webpage/PHP script   <img src='/images/barcode.php?code=12345'/>
//  Directly in your web browser    http://www.example.com/images/barcode.php?code=12345

//Outputs the code as a barcode, surrounded by an asterisk (as per standard)
//Will only output numbers, text will appear as gaps
//Image width is dynamic, depending on how much data there is

//Get the barcode font (called 'free3of9') from here http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/

header("Content-type: image/png");
$file = "images/barcode.png"; // path to base png image
$im = imagecreatefrompng($file); // open the blank image
$string = $_GET['code']; // get the code from URL
imagealphablending($im, true); // set alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($im, true); // save alphablending setting (important)

$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); // colour of barcode

$font_height=40; // barcode font size. anything smaller and it will appear jumbled and will not be able to be read by scanners

$newwidth=((strlen($string)*20)+41); // allocate width of barcode. each character is 20px across, plus add in the asterisk's
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, 40); // generate a new image with correct dimensions

imagecopyresized($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, 40, 10, 10); // copy image to thumb
imagettftext($thumb, $font_height, 0, 1, 40, $black, 'c:\windows\fonts\free3of9.ttf', '*'.$string.'*'); // add text to image

//show the image
imagepng($thumb);
imagedestroy($thumb);
?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i am in the midst of developing a simple ticket barcode scanning project. Do you know if all the handscanners will read the same number back? ps: i don't have a handscanner yet.

Comment: @alex This answer references the font '3 of 9'. 3 of 9, or Code 39, is a widely accepted barcode standard and can be read by almost any barcode scanner. All scanners will read the same value.

Comment: How about, if we need the image to keep in disc, in some folder, so we can later get a reference to it ?

Answer (score 3):

There are [two PEAR packages](http://pear.php.net/search.php?q=barcode&in=packages&x=0&y=0) and [Zend Framework v1.10](http://devzone.zend.com/article/11642-Zend-Framework-1.10.0beta1-Released) will also have BarCode class.

I haven't used any of them though, so I cannot recommend one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for a solution to this, I have worked with [this](http://www.barcodebakery.com/) (adapted the ASP.NET version) and it generated EAN codes without problems.

Comment: It's not free for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a free lib that have php class, jQuery plugin and prototype plugin. It has very
nice examples too [visit](http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-php-class-203.html)

Comment: Brutal.  Couldn't make it more complicated if he tried.